# How do I change the currency display from USD to $?

Tags: commerce

I haven't been able to find a way to change the display of a price from 1.23 USD to $1.23.
How do I change the currency display from USD to $?

Comment: You should add more information to get an answer (are you using Drupal 6, Drupal 7, Ubercart module, Commerce module, other modules?)

Answer (score 2):

You could try

[hook_commerce_currency_info_alter](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!commerce!commerce.api.php/function/hook_commerce_currency_info_alter/7)

For example,

```
function EXAMPLE_commerce_currency_info_alter(&$currencies, $langcode) {
    $currencies['USD']['symbol'] = '$';
    $currencies['USD']['symbol_placement'] = 'before';
    $currencies['USD']['code_placement'] = '';
}
```

See [commerce_commerce_currency_info](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!commerce!includes!commerce.currency.inc/function/commerce_commerce_currency_info/7) for the default currency info implementation.

Comment: good solution (y);