# Change currency code to symbol

Tags: i18n-l10n, commerce

I'm translating the Drupal Commerce site into Japanese.
I want to change the currency code　JPY to symbol "円".
[image]

But keeping rest of the symbols (￥) as it is:

[image]

I referred [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/53953/how-do-i-change-the-currency-display-from-usd-to) and also made changes accordingly. But it didn't help me.
Please guide me.

One more question regarding it, is it possible to use 2 symbols for the same currency? Is there any way to display "円" replacing this "JPY" only? I don't want to use [String Overrides](https://www.drupal.org/project/stringoverrides).

**Edit:** It is ok if I completely change the symbol　from "￥" to "円". I tried doing this by altering **commerce.api.php** file, but it didn't reflect anything.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a form, you can use [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) along with the PHP function [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/tr/function.str-replace.php) to replace JPY with 円. Let me know if you need further help.

EDIT:

```
<?php
  function YOURMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state,$form_id) {
    if ($form_id == 'your_form_id') { 
      print str_replace("JPY", "円", render($content));
    }
  ?>
```

Comment: Yes, probably it appears in forms as shown in above images. I'll try using that hook. Is it possible to change "￥" to "円" as well? But the symbol placement should be "after".

Comment: Sure, you can do that.

Comment: Can you help me explaining how to do that? So that, now I want to replace JPY with "円" and "￥" with "円".

Comment: I can do that when I get home.

Comment: By the way, it should be str_replace. Sorry for that.

Comment: @Akshay I edited my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22107/discussion-between-akshay-and-kartagis).

Comment: @Akshay are you there? Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: can we discuss in chat?